# Fractional logit models in SAS

Tags: sas, stata, glm

Institutionally constrained to using SAS (yes, I know). I have a basic specification I run in Stata/R no problem: fractional logit model (Papke Wooldridge 1996). It's a GLM with a binomial distribution assumption and a logit link function. Data context is stationary time series in the unit interval—percentage data.

In Stata this is easily run as

```
glm Y X, family(binomial) link(logit)
```

in R it is

```
aModel <- glm(Y ~ X, family=binomial(link=logit), data = aDataFrame)
```

Attempting to do this in SAS using proc GLIMMIX:

```
proc glimmix data =aDataTable method = rspl;
class someClassifier anotherClassifier;
model Y = X / dist = binomial link = logit SOLUTION; 
random _residual_; 
run;
```

I'm dealing with a panel dataset, which doesn't matter in R or Stata syntax but appears to be needed information for proc glimmix, hence my inclusion of a 'class' line. I am able to fit models that are fairly close to the original from Stata/R but differ in non trivial ways when we look at individual parameters or predicted values (correlation between different predicted values is about .97). Can anyone advise on the proper way to do a fractional logit in SAS? I think the inclusion of a "random" line as I have above is one source of trouble, as this seems to add random effects to the model via an extra matrix * vector operation.

Comment: Why are you adding variables in your CLASS statement that are not part of your MODEL statement?  Also do you have any missing values?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple it turns out. Need to use: 
     method = QUAD
which will use quasi maximum likelihood estimation, the same as used in Stata and R.